# MySQL Join/WHERE IN performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm running the following query to select all posts liked by a user. The problem is, it takes quite a few seconds for the page to load.

```
SELECT p.*, a.username, a.avatar FROM user_posts p
LEFT JOIN account a ON p.uid=a.id WHERE p.pid in
(select post from user_posts_likes where `by`='$user_id')
ORDER BY `pid` DESC LIMIT $npage, 10";
```

Is there a better way to do this instead of using WHERE IN?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say from here. Prefix the query with explain to get the plan, and add it to your question

Comment: Oh, I think it's pretty likely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try two joins like this:

```
SELECT p.*, a.username, a.avatar FROM user_post_likes l
JOIN post p ON l.post = p.pid
LEFT JOIN account a ON p.uid = a.id
WHERE l.by = 555
```

I deducted the foreign key names from your original query so they might be wrong.
The `555` is an example user id, obviously.